# How to get JVM xmxBytes metrics using Java

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I am trying to get xmxBytes (size) metrics for monitoring jvm but I am unable to get from a java program.

I am using this package import: `java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;`
and this method:

```
RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();         
List<String> argument = runtimeMXBean.getInputArguments();`
```

Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
long max = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
```